# Facing error while copying a file from one dir to another in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

```
string tempKYCFolderPath = "~/Attachments/KYC/KYCTemp/";
string zipfolder = tempKYCFolderPath + "Userdata/";

DirectoryInfo tempPoposalFolder = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(zipfolder));

if (!tempPoposalFolder.Exists)
{
    tempPoposalFolder.Create();
}

string tempUserFolderPath = Path.Combine(tempPoposalFolder.FullName, dr["User Id"] + "_" + dr["Name"].ToString().Trim());
string fileNameAppend = "kyc_" + dr["User Id"].ToString();

DirectoryInfo tempUserFolder = new DirectoryInfo(tempUserFolderPath);

if (!tempUserFolder.Exists)
{
    tempUserFolder.Create();
}

if (dr["PassportFile"] != DBNull.Value)
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(Path.Combine(tempKYCFolderPath, dr["PassportFile"].ToString())));

    if (file != null && file.Exists)
    {
        file.CopyTo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(Path.Combine(tempUserFolderPath , fileNameAppend + "PassportFile" + file.Extension)), true);
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a folder and inside another folder then copying a file from one location and want to paste it inside the 2nd folder but I get an error

> System.ArgumentException
> HResult=0x80070057
> Message=The relative virtual path 'C:/eureeca/solution_Ap3/Attachments/KYC/KYCTemp/Userdata/7_aseel amas amassi/kyc_7PassportFile.jpg' is not allowed here.
> Source=App_Web_jtqcbvoc
>
> StackTrace:
> at Crowd_funding_pages_Admin_UserNiNList.ExporttoCsv(String userid) in c:\eureeca\solution_Ap3\Crowd-funding-pages\Admin\UserNiNList.aspx.cs:line 139
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> [External Code]
> Crowd_funding_pages_Admin_UserNiNList.ExporttoCsv(string) in UserNiNList.aspx.cs"

Answer (score 0):

```
    string baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
                string tempKYCFolderPath = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, "Attachments", "KYC", "KYCTemp");
string zipfolder = Path.Combine(tempKYCFolderPath, "Userdata-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
 Directory.CreateDirectory(zipfolder);
                DirectoryInfo tempPoposalFolder = new DirectoryInfo(zipfolder);
```

Like if you don't know where the project is stored in your PC then you use the first line to get the directory this will give you the physical path of the project so no need to convert it , use it directly